# Add extra information as a pop out on a cell of a DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

How can I have extra information that pops out from a cell in a DataGrid?

In a column of the grid, there is a `YES` or `NO` value. For the `NO` values, I need to offer an explanation for why it is `NO`. Is there something simple/obvious that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can always have a `StatusStrip` and using the `CellMouseEnter` and `CellMouseLeave` events set and remove (respectively) the explanation from the status strip.

```
  private void dgvCellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
  {
      statusStrip1.Text = (sender as DataGridView)[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ToolTipText;
  }

  private void dgvCellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
  {
      statusStrip1.Text = "";
  }
```

As an added feature, you can show that the cell has "extra" info by showing a small mark such as Excel does. Here's a small snippet of code that I use to do the exact same thing:

```
  private void dgvCellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.ColumnIndex != -1) && (e.RowIndex != -1)
      {
          DataGridViewCell dgvCell = (sender as DataGridView)[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

          Pen greenPen = new Pen(Color.Green, 2);
          Boolean hasTooltip = !dgvCell.ToolTipText.Equals("");
          Boolean hasCompleted = (dgvCell.Tag as CellInfo).complete; // CellInfo is a custom class

          if (hasTooltip) && (hasCompleted)
          {
              e.Handled = true;
              e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, e.PaintParts);
              e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, e.CellBounds.Left + 5, e.CellBounds.Top + 2, e.CellBounds.Width - 12, e.CellBounds.Height - 6);
              e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(greenPen, e.CellBounds.Left + 1, e.CellBounds.Top + 1, e.CellBounds.Width - 3, e.CellBounds.Height - 3);
          }
          else if (hasTooltip)
          {
              e.Handled = true;
              e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, e.PaintParts);
              e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Width - 2, e.CellBounds.Height - 2);
          }
          else if (hasCompleted)
          {
              e.Handled = true;
              e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, e.PaintParts);
              e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(greenPen, e.CellBounds.Left + 1, e.CellBounds.Top + 1, e.CellBounds.Width - 3, e.CellBounds.Height - 3);
          }
      }
  }
```

This code draws a blue border around the cell if `hasTooltip` is true, a green border if `hasCompleted` is true, and both borders (with the green one inside) if both are true.

Comment: Where is the StatusStrip displayed?

Comment: You choose where to place it, however, StatusStrips are usually docked to the bottom of the Form.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding a [tooltip](http://forums.asp.net/t/1026193.aspx) (conditionally) to the cell?

Set the tooltip data in ItemDataBound (or dynamic <%# binding)

Comment: No it won't, however you can do that too by adding a CssClass to the cell. i.e. CssClass="has-tooltip". Then use your creativity and add a little "i" icon to indicate there's more information.

Comment: @Marko: isn't this basically a Smart Tag?

Comment: Gah I confused it with ASP.NET's GridView. Disregard my CssClass comment

Comment: The problem with ToolTip is that if you click on the cell the tip won't display.

Comment: What about Context Menu? A little ugly but you could insert an item that will be your explination. You will need to add the code to your CellContentClick event. Just have a switch on which mouse-button was clicked. 

Also, you can dynamically color data grid cells programatically. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995327/programmatically-change-individual-cell-borders-in-a-winforms-datagridview

Answer (score 0):

Try using RowDetails; you can specify RowDetailsTemplate to display detailed information about the row. You can see an example of Row Details [here](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-datagrid-feature-walkthrough.aspx#rowdetails).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the [ASP.NET AJAX PopupControl](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx)? You can pop up on any control and the popup is as easy as placing controls inside a panel such as labels.